# Apply padding to elements that extend beyond the window to the right

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I've got an HTML element that extends beyond the browser window to the right, and I want some spacing between it and the document edge.

The obvious (to me) approach would be to add `padding` to the body so there is some space around everything in the document. But, that doesn't seem to work for things that extend beyond the browser width. Adding a `margin-right` to the element doesn't work either.

This jsfiddle should illustrate the problem pretty clearly:

**https://jsfiddle.net/sccottt/qjajhL05/2/**

I feel like I'm spacing on something obvious here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a neat working solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22302368/749635

This code allows the body element to expand to fit whatever wide elements are inside it:

```
body {
    float: left;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Add width to the body
https://jsfiddle.net/swordys/2cwhudxr/8

```
<p>
  Scroll that way &rarr;
</p>

<div id="wide-thing">
  I want padding on this side &rarr;
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  padding: 25px;
  width: 1500px;
}

#wide-thing {
  background-color: #cf0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: OK, This does add the spacing—though I am hoping there is a more elegant way to do it.In my actual project, the wide elements are images of varying (and unknown) widths. So, to use this solution, I would need to add containers to every image and manage the padding of the document in two separate places. Not the end of the world, but hoping there is maybe a better way to do this.

Comment: If nothing simpler arrives, though, I'll definitely accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @SCCOTTT Updated the answer, no need for extra containers.

Comment: That does work too, but it forces me to update the body when I add elements of different widths in, which isn't great for what I'm working on. I think I've actually found a good solution from this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301513/expand-body-element-width-beyond-width-of-window. This allows the body to expand to whatever width it needs to to fit the elements within it.

Comment: Yep, that can work as well. That's why context is important of what exact problem you're trying to solve and how it should affect rest of the body. Good luck anyways!